# What is considered a creature when using Magic Missile?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Last night when I was DMing I had an NPC wizard who had Magic Missile.  The description states “each dart hits a creature of your choice”.

In this instance what would be considered a creature?  The player characters?

When I look up creature in the manual it looks like “a creature” means an animal and not a humanoid, so Magic Missile would not be effective.  I guess this would be true the other way as well: if I am playing a wizard I could not target most humanoid monsters/villains.

Am I reading this right?

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you have a minute, consider taking the [tour] which will earn you a badge! You can always head over to [help] or [chat] if you have any questions as well. This looks like it already has an answer. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please [edit] it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!